# How do I remove the space after a $ in a String?

Tags: java, regex

I have an input with a space between the $ and the value, and I'd like to remove the space.  This code:

```
System.out.println("This costs $ 5 even.".replaceAll("\\$ ", "$"));
```

should print out:

```
This costs $5 even.
```

but it throws an exception:

```
Illegal group reference: group index is missing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:819)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:955)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at DollarTest.test(DollarTest.java:18)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-):

```
System.out.println("This costs $ 5 even.".replace("$ ", "$"));
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything.  :c

Comment: @james.garriss Works for me

Comment: @james.garriss works for me as well. Define "doesn't do anything".

Comment: Ah.  I see the difference.  I am using `replaceAll()`, because I have multiple replaces to make.  Sorry for not mentioning that in the question.

Comment: replaceAll needs a regular expression. So, you should use fge solution

Comment: @james.garriss My solution should work for any number of replacements.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in a regex replacement string, the `$` is special. It is supposed to be used to refer to a capturing group of the regex itself.

You need to escape it:

```
.replaceAll("\\$ ", "\\$")
```

But [as @pp_ mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35439751/1093528), you are better off using a plain `.replace()` here.

Comment: That's my problem!  I forgot to escape the output.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, `.replace()` isn't an option, because I actually have multiple replaces (something I failed to mention in my question).

Comment: @james.garriss But .replace() DOES replace all occurrences! Yes, I know, the names are confusing. The difference is that arguments to .replace() are not regexes, but plain string literals. See the javadoc :) _do not mix with .replaceFirst()!_

Comment: maybe someone downvoted, because `$` is [an anchor for the end of a string/line](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#dollar) and has nothing to do with referring to a *capturing group* making this propogating incorrect information at best.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative - group the $ and the value, around the space, then concat them in the replacement.

```
String s = "This costs $ 5 even. That costs $ 6 even. This is a $ sign.";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\$)\\s(\\d+)", "$1$2"));
```

Output

```
This costs $5 even. That costs $6 even. This is a $ sign.
```

It also points out a flaw in the other answers

```
String s = "This costs $ 5 even. That costs $ 6 even. This is a $ sign.";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\$ ", "\\$"));
```

Outputs `"$sign"`.

```
This costs $5 even. That costs $6 even. This is a $sign.
```

Comment: @james.garriss - It is a better answer if you do not have a number that follows the dollar sign. See the update

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use following regex to remove any number of spaces between $ and next number.

```
try {
    String data = "This costs $          7 even";
    String resultString = data.replaceAll("(?is)(?<=\\$)\\s*(?=\\d+)", "");
    System.out.println(resultString);

} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

}
```

> Input:

```
This costs $ 5 even
This costs $6 even
This costs $          7 even
This costs $          77 even
This costs $          7.2 even
This costs $          0.21 even
It's cost is between $   5.2 and $   8.3
You don't have to pay top $ for this.
```

> Output:

```
This costs $5 even
This costs $6 even
This costs $7 even
This costs $77 even
This costs $7.2 even
This costs $0.21 even
It's cost is between $5.2 and $8.3
You don't have to pay top $ for this.
```